# Mouse buttons and wheel change and get wrong configuration

Tags: mouse

I'm using a generic mouse¹ in a fresh Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installation² and I have this problem that, suddenly, without any specific movement or clicking the wheel changes to control the volume and the click on the wheel stops working. After an unspecific time the mouse works back normally and some time after it came back to works weird.

Any idea?

Thank you very much!

¹ Gembird MUS-ERGO-01 Ergonomic 6-button wired optical mouse https://gembird.com/item.aspx?id=10489

² I got the same problem in the previous Ubuntu 18 installation

Comment: Please be precise with details; fresh Ubuntu 22 install?  So this is a Ubuntu Core 22 server install? (*the year format is reserved for specialist server products since 2016; ie. 22 != 22.04*)

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hardware problem. I checked in different computers with different OS and the problem still. I'm getting a new mouse thanks to the guarantee.

Sorry if you waste time reading this.

Greetings,
ifrit.